# Using JSch to SFTP when one must also switch user

Tags: java, unix, sftp, sudo, jsch

I am using JSch in a Java client to connect to a remote server and get some files using SFTP. The following code has been working fine for me: -

```
JSch ssh = new JSch();
JSch.setConfig(FileTransferConstants.STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING, FileTransferConstants.NO);
Session session = ssh.getSession(userName, host, port);
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel(FileTransferConstants.SFTP);
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
sftp.cd(remoteDirectoryPath);
sftp.lcd(localDirectoryPath);

sftp.get(remoteDirectoryPath + remoteFileName, remoteFileName);
```

The problem is that there has now been a change of site policy. I am no longer permitted to log on directly as this user (userName above). I must first log on as my personal user and then su into the user that has access to the files I want to SFTP.

I don't think there is anyway I can refactor the above code to achieve this and so I have started looking at using a shell or exec channel instead. I have had little success so far and cannot seem to find any examples on the web, so I would be very grateful for any advice or pointers in the right direction. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can do this directly with JSch. But with some modification of its code, it's probably doable.

*Note that my answer assumes that the server is *nix-based (what is backed by your reference to `su`) and uses OpenSSH SFTP server.*

---

You have to open SSH "exec" channel, to execute something like:

```
sudo /bin/sftp-server
```

But on top of that channel, you need to build the `ChannelSftp` instance, not `ChannelExec`.

So you will need to implement `Session.openChannel`-like method, that will open `exec` channel, but create `ChannelSftp` for it.

---

For some background, see [how it's possible to do `sudo` with WinSCP SFTP client](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su#sudo).

Note that while the FAQ claims, that you won't be able to use password for the `sudo`, that's true for WinSCP. But as you have a full control of the session with JSch, you may be able to feed the password to `sudo`.

For that you might override the `ChannelSftp.start()` to write the password to the channel input, before starting the actual SFTP session.

You still need the `requiretty` option be off, as the SFTP cannot work with TTY.

---

For general considerations when automating operations using a different/root account, see:
[Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663)