# Follow up to: Using JSch to SFTP when one must also switch user

Tags: java, sftp, scp, jsch, su

This is a follow up to:

[Using JSch to SFTP when one must also switch user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975994/using-jsch-to-sftp-when-one-must-also-switch-user)

This issue has been on the back burner since I asked the original question while our server management team reviews their policies, but I am now picking it up again!

What I want to do is to use JSch to connect to a remote server and then use sftp or scp to access some files - as per the code example in the original question. The issue is that these files are owned by another user and so I need to su to that user and then provide a password before issuing the sftp or scp command.

This cannot be done in JSch and this is right because it is a security risk to be able to send the password through the exec channel. So these are options I have going forward as I see them.

1. Override JSch functionality. Martin has very helpfully provided some guidance in an answer to the original question as to how this could be done by and how the password may be passed in "through the back door". But I am not confident in my own ability to override the JSch code and once again, even if successful, I would be circumventing a security feature that is there for legitimate reasons, so I am reluctant to attempt this.
2. On the server, grant my user password-less access to the other user. This is a no as my server management team will not agree to this.
3. Have a server-side .sh script that can be run by my user to gain access to the files. Again, this is a no as my server management team will not agree to it!
4. Automate a putty session i.e. phsically open putty and pass commands to the putty session line by line from the Java client.
5. Give up! Should I accept that I am trying to do something here that should not be automated and simply have a manual test instead?

I would be extremely grateful for any thoughts/guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to do something here that should not be automated.

That's correct in principle.

The only correct automatic solution is to directly login with the user that has access to the files. Everything else is just a hack or working around your security policy. Ideally you should authenticate with a dedicated private key to allow monitoring the access from your application and to be able to control the access (e.g. temporary turning it off, without affecting other uses of the same account).

Though I can imagine that your system administrators won't allow you the direct login, because they cannot foresee what (if any) security issues it brings.

Comment: Many thanks for always taking the time to address these questions Martin. You have confirmed what I thought - and you are right, my administrators will not allow me direct access as the other user. I will make my team aware of our exchanges here on stackoverflow and hopefully we will all agree that this particular test will need to have at least some manual steps.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to share that I have got a solution working for this question by adapting the sample JSch example, JumpHosts.

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java

Overriding the inherited methods in the static class MyUserInfo allowed me to automatically accept prompt boxes, input boxes, etc without physically having to use the keyboard, so I have a fully automated test as desired.

It's great that the jcraft team provide such useful worked examples. Thanks for everyone who took the time to read and consider my question.

Edit: As per Martin's comment, I should point out that this only works if you have a special rule in SSH configuration that allows direct user2 login from localhost (while not allowing direct remote login). That's not sudo. So this cannot work in general.

Comment: How does the port forwarding example relate to sudo?

Comment: If you call the port forwarding example with two arguments: user1@hostname and user2@localhost where user1 is my personal user and user2 is the user that has access to the files that I want (that user1 doesn't have direct access to) it works a treat!

Comment: But that can work only if you have a special rule in SSH configuration that allows direct `user2` login from `localhost` (while not allowing direct remote login). That's not sudo. So this cannot work in general. Worth mentioning in the answer.