# Opening ChannelSftp channel to transfer the file after using sudo

Tags: java, unix, sftp, file-transfer, jsch

This Below code works perfectly when we don't need to switch user before we open sftp channel for file transfer. Issue comes when we need to switch user.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession(user, HOST, port);
session.setPassword(PASS);
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(properties);
session.connect();

/*** Here I want use the command "sudo su - weblogic" 
**** then put my password ****
**** so that I can switch to weblogic to transfer the file ****/

sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
sftpChannel.connect();
System.out.println("SFTP Channel Created.");

byte[] bufr = new byte[(int) new File(fileName).length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
fis.read(bufr);
ByteArrayInputStream fileStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bufr);
sftpChannel.put(fileStream, targetLoc+"/"+fileName);
fis.close();
```

Could anyone help me out how to do that ?

I also tried to do the below to switch the user which also works fine. but then SFTP channel is not available.

```
session = connection.openSession();
session.requestPTY("dumb", 500, 0, 0, 0, null);
session.startShell();
writer = new PrintWriter(session.getStdin());
reader = new InputStreamReader(session.getStdout());
writer.print("sudo su - weblogic\n");
waitFor("[sudo] password for <user>: ");
writer.print("<password>\n");
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am NOT able to understand anything there. Its so much content. may be I need to give some more time to it to actually understand what they are saying and what can work for me.

Comment: What you want to do is 1) Nearly impossible, at least not without an advanced knowledge about administrating the SSH/SFTP server. What you probably do not have, if you do not understand my answer there. 2) Bad thing to do in general.

Comment: Your question is duplicate. If you do not understand my answer to the other question, you will have to tell us, what it is that you do not understand.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for you dedication. I really appreciate it. Give me something ..I will try to understand it and then will comment here. Again thanks for your time :)

Comment: I do not know what you want me to give you.

Comment: Below looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975994/using-jsch-to-sftp-when-one-must-also-switch-user