# Modifying a remote file while connected to a server through SSH using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ssh, ssh.net

I have successfully established a connection to a remote Linux server using the SSH.NET package with the following code (I am using a `ShellStream` because I have to use `sudo su`):

```
using (var client = new SshClient(server, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();

    List<string> commands = new List<string>();
    commands.Add("sudo su - user");
    commands.Add("vi test.properties");

    ShellStream shellStream = client.CreateShellStream("xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);

    // Execute commands under root account
    foreach (string command in commands) {
        WriteStream(command, shellStream);              
    }

    client.Disconnect();
}

private static void WriteStream(string cmd, ShellStream stream)
{
    stream.WriteLine(cmd + "; echo this-is-the-end");
    while (stream.Length == 0)
        Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

I am trying to edit the `test.properties` file that is in the remote Linux server using a C# function that I created.

My code (using C# in Visual Studio) that is used to modify the text file is uses `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`, but it does not recognize the path of the remote server, for example:

The text file in the Linux server is in this location: `/home/user/test.properties`, so I am using this in my code:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText("/home/user/test.properties")
```

I am getting the following error:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\home\user\test.properties'

For some reason it tries to look in my local file system instead of the remote server.

Is there a different approach I should be taking?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to modify remote files, use SFTP. In SSH.NET that's what `SftpClient` is for.

---

Though as you seem to need to use elevated privileges (`su`) – an important factor that your question title fails to mention – it's way more difficult. The right solution is to avoid the need for `su`. See somewhat related:
[Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663).

Another option would be to try to execute the SFTP server under `su`. Though that would require modification of SSH.NET code. See related Java question:
[Using JSch to SFTP when one must also switch user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42975994/850848)

---

If you want to keep your current shell approach with `su`, you are stuck with simulating shell commands. Note that connecting to SSH server won't make other .NET classes (like the `File`) magically be able to work with remote files (even if SFTP was possible, let only when it is not, due to the `su` requirement).

The easiest way to read remote file using shell is using the `cat` command:

```
cat /home/user/test.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so after finishing the task, this is what I did since asking the question here:

1.After your(@Martin Prikryl) response I've tried using a combination of SSH and WinSCP:

- WinSCP to download the file.
- .NET to modify the locally downloaded file.
- WinSCP to upload the file(and deleting it from the local folder afterwards).
- SSH to move the file to its appropriate location in the server.

I discarded this solution because it worked pretty well in the lower environment,
but in the production I had permissions issues so I couldn't even download it, let alone that it might be a security issue(its a sensitive file).

2.My next solution was using only SSH to simulate shell commands, as you previously mentioned, I was limited to that because I was stuck using sudo su.

- I connected to the server with SSH and used the 'sed' command to only show lines that contain specific words(instead of using cat to get the whole file).
- I then used my .NET code to pull the values that I needed for my GET operation
- For the POST operation I used 'sed' again to replace lines.